# Unknown command 'DEBUG:myapp'

Tags: node.js, shell, express, command-line, express-generator

So I have done exactly what 
[Express Generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) told me to do.
I have also installed express like this:

```
npm install express --save
```

But then when I run

```
DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www
```

I got this

```
Unknown command 'DEBUG=myapp'
```

And Google couldn't help. Does anyone know potentially what could cause this?
I have a fish shell, also doesn't work in bash shell.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my terminal when i run this]

Comment: Woah I don't even remember I had this problem. It was simply because of my shell wrapper -- fish. stupid fish.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message that it returned. Simply run:

```
env DEBUG=myapp ./bin/www
```

Then go to http://localhost:3000.

Comment: and if you want debug express like here http://expressjs.com/guide/debugging.html use env DEBUG="express:*" node ./bin/www (add quotation marks)

Answer (score 1):

express is different from express-generator. Express generator sets up a folder structure with all the important files you need. If you need the generator run

`npm i express-generator -g`

then

`express [app-name]`

where [app-name] is the name of the app you want to create. You can check this link for more options https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

```
DEBUG=myapp:* ./bin/www
```

Comment: fish: Unknown command 'DEBUG=myapp'. 
fish: Illegal command name 'DEBUG=myapp:*'

Comment: are you on mac or window?